# Specify the filename of the CSV inside the zip file on Azure Data Factory Copy

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline in Azure Data Factory using the `Copy Data` functionality.

It is copying a view from Azure SQL to a CSV file on a Blob Storage. I have chosen to Zip the file and name it `Output_{year}{month}{day}.zip`.

Everything is working perfectly, however the content of the zip file contains the csv which has a GUID for a filename. How can I make it so that the filename inside the zip is: `Output_{year}{month}{day}.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, currently there is no option in ADF to customize the file name inside the generated zip file.

One possible trick is you can use two copy activities, the 1st one copy to Output_{year}{month}{day}.csv, the 2nd one copy from that file to Output_{year}{month}{day}.zip with "[copyBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#azure-blob-as-sink)" set to "PreserveHierarchy" (default).